Nomu Hoods creation
In MHA how was the Nomu Hood created. Most of the nomu are destructive and blindly follow orders but they can be handled with only a little struggle. But when Nomu Hood came along everything changed, he gained intelligence along the way. He also had the ability to create other nomu as he wished. He was pretty much unstoppable. (heads up i have only read the manga till book 20 so if it tells in others i don't have yet please have mercy)

By Nomu hood, do you mean the one that Endevour fought? Sorry, it's been a while since I watched or read MHA.

Yes, that is his name and no worries just happy someone may know
